# Getting AssertionError while using ObjectifyService.register

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am in the middle of trying to refactor some of my data models, but I've run into a problem that I don't understand.

Originally I had a simple data model comprised of 3 entity classes, which looked something like this:

```
@Entity
public final class Teacher {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String primarySubject;

  public Teacher() {}

  public Teacher(String primarySubject) {
    this.primarySubject = primarySubject;
  }

  //getters & setters
}

@Entity
public final class Student {
  @Id
  private String username;
  @Load
  @Index
  private Ref<Teacher> homeRoomTeacher;

  public Student() {}

  public Student(String username, Teacher teacher) {
    this.username = username;
    homeRoomTeacher = Ref.create(teacher);
  }

  //getters & setters
}

@Entity
public final class School {
  @Id
  private String name;
  @Load
  private Set<Ref<Teacher>> teachers;
  @Load
  private Set<Ref<Student>> students;

  public School() {}

  public School(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  //getters & setters
}
```

And this all worked fine.

But we decided that it would be more useful for us to embed the entities directly instead of Refs...

```
@Entity
@Embed
public final class Teacher {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String primarySubject;

  public Teacher() {}

  public Teacher(String primarySubject) {
    this.primarySubject = primarySubject;
  }

  //getters & setters
}

@Entity
@Embed
public final class Student {
  @Id
  private String username;
  @Index
  private Ref<Teacher> homeRoomTeacher;

  public Student() {}

  public Student(String username, Teacher teacher) {
    this.username = username;
    homeRoomTeacher = Ref.create(teacher);
  }

  //getters & setters
}

@Entity
public final class School {
  @Id
  private String name;
  private Set<Teacher> teachers;
  private Set<Student> students;

  public School() {}

  public School(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  //getters & setters
}
```

After making those changes, then all of our junit tests started to fail with an AssertionError during registration of the School class in our test setup methods which look like:

```
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
    helper.setUp();
    ObjectifyService.register(Teacher.class);
    ObjectifyService.register(Student.class);
    ObjectifyService.register(School.class);

    // more setup
  }
```

The AssertionError doesn't appear until the line that registers the School class, and according to the stack trace is being thrown from the method "[com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.enterCollection](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/translate/CreateContext.java?r=95ac0ddaafaffa83ac6c2734adf5a652781b37ce#78)" but I'm not certain how to go about fixing it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error you are getting is to do with the fact that you are trying to register a class which you have annotated with @Embed.

The objectify documentation clearly states that @Embed classes do not have to be registered - maybe this is the cause of the issue.

Also, I'm not 100% sure on this but I don't think you need @Id on an embedded class.

I would suggest you give the following changes a go:

```
@Embed
public final class Teacher {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String primarySubject;

  public Teacher() {}

  public Teacher(String primarySubject) {
    this.primarySubject = primarySubject;
  }

  //getters & setters
}

@Embed
public final class Student {
  @Id
  private String username;
  @Index
  private Ref<Teacher> homeRoomTeacher;

  public Student() {}

  public Student(String username, Teacher teacher) {
    this.username = username;
    homeRoomTeacher = Ref.create(teacher);
  }

  //getters & setters
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception 
{
    helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
    helper.setUp();
    ObjectifyService.register(School.class);

    // more setup
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I actually made those very changes over the weekend, but I still get the exact same error when registering the School class. By the way, I'd note that with my initial setup the error wasn't thrown on the registration of either the Student or the Teacher classes (which if the @Embed annotation was problematic you'd expect), but only on the School class.